# Is there a way to use windowing functions to simplify this query?

Tags: t-sql, ssms-2014

I have some data, real-world example. In order to display the data a particular way, the data is stored in such a way that I have to manipulate it to get the results I want. Essentially, there are two different types of invoices: a pre-invoice (P) where amounts are billed before an order is processed; and a standard invoice (I) where the remainder is billed after shipping. You would expect, under ordinary circumstances, that the standard invoice would have the pre-invoice amount subtracted out of it, e.g., if the pre-invoice was for $2 and the order was for $10 that the standard invoice would be $8. Instead, though, the standard invoice is stored as $10.

Below is a fully operational query (That query's operational! It's a trap!) that both populates the data and returns the results I want. The goal is to take the invoice amount and if it's a pre-invoice, return that amount; but if it's a standard invoice, to "use up" the value of the pre-invoice and return a new amount, minimum zero. I've included six scenarios, because the pre-invoice could be any amount and could technically be required at any time.

Any assistance on this would be much appreciated. I tried some windowing functions, including UNBOUNDED PRECEDING type stuff, but it always seemed like I needed to be recursive and go into an infinite loop. Hence my brute-force approach, below.

```
DECLARE @PData TABLE (
     CustNum        INT
    ,TransNum       INT
    ,InvType        NVARCHAR(1)
    ,InvAmt         DECIMAL(5,2)
    ,CRank          INT
    ,TRank          INT
    ,ModInvAmt      DECIMAL(5,2)
    )

INSERT INTO @PData (
     CustNum
    ,TransNum
    ,InvType
    ,InvAmt
    )

    VALUES
     (124, 1,'P',2)
    ,(124, 2,'I',10)
    ,(124, 3,'I',10)
    ,(153, 4,'I',10)
    ,(153, 5,'P',2)
    ,(153, 6,'I',10)
    ,(324, 7,'I',10)
    ,(324, 8,'I',10)
    ,(324, 9,'P',2)
    ,(441,10,'P',12)
    ,(441,11,'I',10)
    ,(441,12,'I',10)
    ,(455,13,'I',10)
    ,(455,14,'P',12)
    ,(455,15,'I',10)
    ,(667,16,'I',10)
    ,(667,17,'I',10)
    ,(667,18,'P',12)

UPDATE pd1
    SET CRank = pd2.CDR
        FROM @PData pd1
            JOIN (SELECT CustNum, TransNum, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CustNum) AS CDR
                    FROM @PData) pd2
                ON pd1.TransNum = pd2.TransNum

UPDATE pd1
    SET TRank = pd2.TDR
        FROM @PData pd1
            JOIN (SELECT CustNum, TransNum, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CustNum ORDER BY TransNum) AS TDR
                    FROM @PData) pd2
                ON pd1.TransNum = pd2.TransNum

DECLARE  @Counter1      INT
        ,@Counter2      INT
        ,@CBal          DECIMAL(5,2)
        ,@TNum          INT
        ,@IAmt          DECIMAL(5,2)

SET @Counter1 = 0

WHILE @Counter1 < (SELECT MAX(CRank) FROM @PData)
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter1 += 1
        SET @CBal = 0
        SET @Counter2 = 0
            WHILE @Counter2 < (SELECT MAX(TRank) FROM @PData WHERE CRank = @Counter1)
                BEGIN
                    SET @Counter2 += 1
                    SET @TNum = (SELECT TransNum FROM @PData WHERE CRank = @Counter1 AND TRank = @Counter2)
                    SET @IAmt = (SELECT InvAmt FROM @PData WHERE TransNum = @TNum)
                    IF (SELECT InvType FROM @PData WHERE TransNum = @TNum) = 'P'
                        BEGIN
                            UPDATE @PData SET ModInvAmt = @IAmt WHERE TransNum = @TNum
                            SET @CBal += -@IAmt 
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            UPDATE @PData SET ModInvAmt = (ABS(@IAmt+@CBal)+(@IAmt+@CBal))/2 -- MINIMUM = 0
                                 WHERE TransNum = @TNum
                            SET @CBal += (@IAmt - (ABS(@IAmt+@CBal)+(@IAmt+@CBal))/2)
                        END                 
                END
    END

SELECT   CustNum
        ,TransNum
        ,InvType
        ,InvAmt
        ,ModInvAmt
 FROM @PData
```

Here are the results I get:
[image]

I wouldn't normally report the original invoice amount--just the new one--but I've included it here so it's more clear how it changed.

```
 CustNum TransNum InvType InvAmt  ModInvAmt
 124      1         P     2.00      2.00
 124      2         I    10.00      8.00
 124      3         I    10.00     10.00
 153      4         I    10.00     10.00
 153      5         P     2.00      2.00
 153      6         I    10.00      8.00
 324      7         I    10.00     10.00
 324      8         I    10.00     10.00
 324      9         P     2.00      2.00
 441     10         P    12.00     12.00
 441     11         I    10.00      0.00
 441     12         I    10.00      8.00
 455     13         I    10.00     10.00
 455     14         P    12.00     12.00
 455     15         I    10.00      0.00
 667     16         I    10.00     10.00
 667     17         I    10.00     10.00
 667     18         P    12.00     12.00
```

Comment: My image at the end isn't showing up?

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Done, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it recursivly with common table expressions.

Best regards
Peter

```
DECLARE @PData TABLE (
     CustNum        INT
    ,TransNum       INT
    ,InvType        NVARCHAR(1)
    ,InvAmt         DECIMAL(5,2)
    )

INSERT INTO @PData (
     CustNum
    ,TransNum
    ,InvType
    ,InvAmt
    )

    VALUES
 (124, 1,'P',2)
,(124, 2,'I',10)
,(124, 3,'I',10)
,(153, 4,'I',10)
,(153, 5,'P',2)
,(153, 6,'I',10)
,(324, 7,'I',10)
,(324, 8,'I',10)
,(324, 9,'P',2)
,(441,10,'P',12)
,(441,11,'I',10)
,(441,12,'I',10)
,(455,13,'I',10)
,(455,14,'P',12)
,(455,15,'I',10)
,(455,19,'I',10)
,(667,16,'I',10)
,(667,17,'I',10)
,(667,18,'P',12)

;WITH Data as (
    SELECT
        CustNum,
        TransNum,
        InvType,
        InvAmt, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custNum ORDER BY Transnum ASC) row,
        CASE WHEN InvType = 'P' THEN cast(-1*InvAmt AS DECIMAL(5,2)) ELSE 0 END prepaidAmt
    FROM 
        @PData
), modified as(
    SELECT 
        CustNum,
        TransNum,
        InvType,
        InvAmt,
        prepaidAmt,
        row, 
        InvAmt  total
    FROM Data d1 
        WHERE row = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      
        d2.CustNum,
        d2.TransNum,
        d2.InvType,
        d2.InvAmt,
        CASE 
        WHEN 
            d2.InvAmt+m.prepaidAmt  < 0 
        THEN  
            CAST (d2.InvAmt+m.prepaidAmt AS DECIMAL(5,2))  
        ELSE 
            CASE 
            WHEN 
                d2.invtype = 'P' 
            THEN 
                CAST(-1*d2.invamt AS DECIMAL(5,2)) 
            ELSE 
                0 
            END   
        END ,
        d2.row, 
        CASE 
        WHEN 
            d2.InvAmt+m.prepaidAmt <0 
        THEN 
            0 
        ELSE  
            CAST( d2.InvAmt+m.prepaidAmt AS DECIMAL(5,2))  
        END
    FROM Data d2
    JOIN modified m 
    ON 
        m.CustNum = d2.CustNum and 
        m.row = d2.row-1
)
SELECT 
    m.CustNum,
    m.TransNum,
    m.InvType,
    m.InvAmt,
    m.total
FROM modified m
ORDER BY 
    custnum, 
    transnum
```

Comment: Wow...that's fairly brilliant! Thanks!